# Unable to Use Twilio classes in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, twilio

I am trying to integrate Twilio with Salesforce. My usecase is to automate sending messages from Salesforce. Following this blog (http://www.asagarwal.com/step-by-step-guide-on-sending-receiving-sms-from-in-salesforce/).
Installed Twilio in Salesforce. Trying to use Twilio classes but unable to do as it is showing Invalid Type for the Twilio class.

Why am I unable to use the classes ?

[image: Errorwhile saving Apex Class]

Comment: Can you confirm that the Twilio Salesforce helper library was installed properly and you can see the package components in your org?

Comment: Yes, it is installed properly. We can see the TwilioRestClient class in console but when trying to use it., it says invalid type as shown in above screenshot

Comment: Have you tried following the installation instructions here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/salesforce